# Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch when installing nginx-1.7.8 from source

Tags: nginx, centos, vagrant, chef-infra

I get the following error when running `vagrant up --provision` to set up my development environment with vagrant...

```
==> default: [2014-12-08T20:33:51+00:00] ERROR: remote_file[http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.7.8.tar.gz] (nginx::source line 58) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch: Checksum on resource (0510af) does not match checksum on content (12f75e)
```

My chef JSON has the following for nginx:

```
"nginx": {
"version": "1.7.8",
"user": "deploy",
"init_style": "init",
"modules": [
  "http_stub_status_module",
  "http_ssl_module",
  "http_gzip_static_module"
],
"passenger": {
  "version": "4.0.53",
  "gem_binary": "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims/gem"
},
"configure_flags": [
  "--add-module=/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-3.0.18/ext/nginx"
],
"gzip_types": [
  "text/plain",
  "text/html",
  "text/css",
  "text/xml",
  "text/javascript",
  "application/json",
  "application/x-javascript",
  "application/xml",
  "application/xml+rss"
]}
```

and Cheffile has the following cookbook:

```
cookbook 'nginx'
```

How do I resolve the Checksum mismatch?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [nginx cookbook](https://github.com/miketheman/nginx/) requires you to edit the `checksum` attribute when using another version of nginx. The `remote_file` resource that is causing you an error is:

```rb
remote_file nginx_url do
  source   nginx_url
  checksum node['nginx']['source']['checksum']
  path     src_filepath
  backup   false
end
```

You need to update the checksum value. Specifically `node['nginx']['source']['checksum']`.

So in your JSON, you would add this line:

```
"source": {"checksum": "insert checksum here" }
```

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, the checksum is SHA256. You can generate the checksum of the file like so:

```
shasum -a 256 nginx-1.7.8.tar.gz
```

Comment: I've tried this `openssl md4 nginx-1.6.2.tar.gz` to generate the checksum but still receive the same error. Any idea how you'd get the checksum?

Comment: Your JSON file says your're trying to use `nginx-1.7.8.tar.gz`. You're generating the checksum on the wrong file.

Comment: @AlexMeng I actually have 1.6.2 version in my JSON file. The above JSON file is of whatgrove. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I believe the nginx checksums are md5, not md4.

Comment: The recipe is using [remote_file](https://docs.getchef.com/resource_remote_file.html) which needs a sha 256 checksum, i.e. `shasum -a 256 nginx-1.7.8.tar.gz`