# Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch when installing nginx-1.4.4 from source

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, checksum, chef-solo

I am having the error described here:

[Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch when installing nginx-1.7.8 from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366774/chefexceptionschecksummismatch-when-installing-nginx-1-7-8-from-source)

However, that fix does not work for me.

Following the suggestions on that page, I created a shasum:

```
  shasum -a 256 nginx-1.4.4.tar 

  ed744d916a19e426fd6885e14036d64156f4b6f6aca1d22a1b9307de8d46e8d3  nginx-1.4.4.tar
```

then I opened this file:

```
  vi /opt/chef/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/source.rb
```

and I found this block:

```
  remote_file nginx_url do
    source   nginx_url
    checksum node['nginx']['source']['checksum']
    path     src_filepath
    backup   false
  end
```

which I changed to this:

```
  remote_file nginx_url do
    source   nginx_url
    checksum 'ed744d916a19e426fd6885e14036d64156f4b6f6aca1d22a1b9307de8d46e8d3'
    path     src_filepath
    backup   false
  end
```

but I continue to get this error:

```
  Recipe: nginx::source
    * yum_package[pcre-devel] action install (up to date)
    * yum_package[openssl-devel] action install (up to date)
    * remote_file[http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.4.4.tar.gz] action create

      ================================================================================
      Error executing action `create` on resource 'remote_file[http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.4.4.tar.gz]'
      ================================================================================

      Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch
      ----------------------------------
      Checksum on resource (ed744d) does not match checksum on content (7c989a)

      Resource Declaration:
      ---------------------
      # In /opt/chef/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/source.rb

       58: remote_file nginx_url do
       59:   source   nginx_url
       60:   checksum 'ed744d916a19e426fd6885e14036d64156f4b6f6aca1d22a1b9307de8d46e8d3'
       61:   path     src_filepath
       62:   backup   false
       63: end
       64: 

      Compiled Resource:
      ------------------
      # Declared in /opt/chef/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/source.rb:58:in `from_file'

      remote_file("http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.4.4.tar.gz") do
        provider Chef::Provider::RemoteFile
        action [:create]
        retries 0
        retry_delay 2
        default_guard_interpreter :default
        source ["http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.4.4.tar.gz"]
        use_etag true
        use_last_modified true
        declared_type :remote_file
        cookbook_name :nginx
        recipe_name "source"
        checksum "ed744d916a19e426fd6885e14036d64156f4b6f6aca1d22a1b9307de8d46e8d3"
        path "/var/chef/cache/nginx-1.4.4.tar.gz"
        atomic_update true
      end


  Running handlers:
  [2016-02-16T15:40:44+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
  Running handlers complete
  [2016-02-16T15:40:44+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
  Chef Client failed. 5 resources updated in 19 seconds
  [2016-02-16T15:40:44+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
  [2016-02-16T15:40:44+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
  [2016-02-16T15:40:44+00:00] ERROR: remote_file[http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.4.4.tar.gz] (nginx::source line 58) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch: Checksum on resource (ed744d) does not match checksum on content (7c989a)
  [2016-02-16T15:40:44+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Does anyone have any advice?

I am running this inside of vagrant, on my local machine (a Mac).

Comment: Weird.. are you sure that your `shasum` executable accepts the `-a` parameter as you expect it? I get the exepcted `7c989a58e5408c9593da0bebcd0e4ffc3d892d1316ba5042ddb0be5b0b4102b9`as result of `curl http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.4.4.tar.gz | shasum -a 256 -`.

Comment: `remote_file[http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.4.4.tar.gz] action create` Seems you're downloading a `.tar.gz` and not the `.tar` you checksummed...

Comment: @Tensibai -- good point

Comment: @StephenKing -- I hardcoded "7c989a58e5408c9593da0bebcd0e4ffc3d892d1316ba5042ddb0be5b0b4102b9" and that got me past that error. Thank you. Now I get
   Error executing action `reload` on resource 'service[nginx]'    
    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
I suppose I could start a new StackOverflow question for that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this was resolved in comments above, but for the record you need to make sure the checksum exactly the file being downloaded. This can be confusing in cases with gzip compression.

Answer (score 0):

Run sha256sum command against the file and use the output as checksum. Seems like you're using md5 or sha1 hash algorithm as checksum